# Joint law of Brownian motion maximum and its values at different points

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion on $[0, T]$ and let $\tau$ be the (a.s. unique) moment at which it attains its maximum value: $M = \sup_{t \in [0, T]} B(t) = B (\tau)$.

There is a well-known formula for the joint density of $(M, B(T))$, but I cannot find a joint density of $(M, B(u))$ for $u < T$. Is it possible? I found a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3856310/1132955), but the given answer is incomplete.

Also, I am looking for the distribution of $(M, B(u), B(v))$ with some $0<u<v<T$. If the previous question is doable, maybe the joint pdf of this vector may also be found?

---

Finally, I am trying to compute $\mathbb{E} \{ \tau B(u) \}$ for some fixed $u$. If I knew the joint law from above, I'd be able to find this easily. But maybe there is a chance to calculate this without knowing the joint pdf?

Comment: Take a look at Borodin's handbook of Brownian motion, this joint law might be in there.

Comment: @ThomasKojar, I have tried already... Unfortunately, I didn't find it. Maybe I should try again.

Comment: @ThomasKojar, Borodin & Salminen have only the usual $(M, B(T))$ pdf (formulas 1.1.7 and 1.1.8)

Comment: You can also try artificially creating it i.e. writing 
$$M_{T}=\max(\sup_{0\leq t\leq u} B_{t}, B_{u}+\sup_{u\leq t\leq T} B_{t}-B_{u})$$

$$=\max(M_{u}, B_{u}+\sup_{u\leq t\leq T} B_{t}-B_{u})$$

So if you condition on $B_{u}=c$

$$M_{T}=\max(M_{u}, c+Z),$$

for independent variable $Z$ and the law of $M_{u}$ with $B_{u}$ is known.

Comment: @ThomasKojar, and the same trick should give me the density of $(M_T, B(u), B(v))$, right?

Comment: you can try. If you figure it out, please post it below as answer.

Comment: @ThomasKojar, thank you very much for your help! I still wonder, maybe you have an idea of how to calculate $\mathbb{E} \{ \tau B_u \}$ without using these densities? They seem quite heavy. Maybe there's a simpler way...

Comment: @ThomasKojar, I initially thought to apply Malliavin integration by parts, but I don't know whether $\tau$ is differentiable and what is its derivative if it is...

Comment: Can you create a new question for the  question about tau?

Comment: @ThomasKojar, here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4883793/1132955

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Thomas Kojar's suggestion does help to solve the problem. Let $0 < u < v < T$. Then, since
$$
M_T = \max \{ M_u, B_u + \max_{t \in [u, T]} ( B_t - B_u ) \}
= \max \{ M_u, B_u + M_{T-u}^* \},
$$
by law of total probability we obtain
$$
\mathbb{P} \{ M_T < x, B_u < \alpha \}
= \int_{-\infty}^\alpha
\mathbb{P} \{ M_{T-u}^* < x - z \}
\cdot \mathbb{P} \{ M_u < x, \ B_u \in dz \}.
$$
By
$$
\mathbb{P} \{ M_u \in d\xi, \ B_u \in dz \}
= \frac{2 ( 2\xi - z)}{u^{3/2} \sqrt{2 \pi}} 
\exp \left( -\frac{( 2 \xi - z )^2}{2u} \right)
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{P} \{ M_T < x \} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi T}} \int_0^x e^{-q^2/2T} dq
$$
we obtain
$$
\mathbb{P} \{ M_T < x, B_u < \alpha \}
=
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi (T-u)}}
\int_{-\infty}^\alpha
\int_0^{x-z} \exp \left( -\frac{q^2}{2(T-u)} \right) dq
\int_0^x
\frac{2 ( 2\xi - z)}{u^{3/2} \sqrt{2 \pi}} 
\exp \left( -\frac{( 2 \xi - z )^2}{2u} \right)
\, d\xi \, dz.
$$
Simplifying, we obtain
$$
\mathbb{P} \{ M_T < x, B_u < \alpha \}
= \frac{2}{\pi u^{3/2} \sqrt{T-u}}
\int_{-\infty}^\alpha
\int_0^x
\int_0^x
(2\xi-z)
\exp \left( -\frac{(q+z)^2}{2(T-u)} -\frac{( 2 \xi - z )^2}{2u} \right)
\, dq \, d\xi \, dz.
$$

---

Okay, now I probably see how to apply this procedure to finding the law of $(M_T, B_u, B_v)$:
$$
\mathbb{P} \{ M_T < x, \ B_u < y, \ B_v < z \}
=
\mathbb{P} \left\{
\begin{gathered}
M_u < x, \ B_u + M_{v-u}^* < x, B_u + B_{v-u}^* + M_{T-v}^{**} < x, \\
B_u < \alpha, \ B_u + B_{v-u}^* < \beta
\end{gathered}
\right\},
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
B_t^* & = B_{t+u} - B_u, \quad t \in [0, v-u], & M_t^* & = \max_{t \in [0, v - u]} B_t^*, \\
B_t^{**} & = B_{t+v} - B_v, \quad t \in [0, T - v], & M_{T-v}^{**} & = \max_{t \in [ 0, T - v ]} B_t^{**}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Most importantly, random variables with different numbers of stars (0, 1 and 2) are independent of each other. This motivates us to condition in $(B_{v-u}^*, M_{v-u}^*)$ (one star)
$$
\mathbb{P} \{ M_T < x, \ B_u < y, \ B_v < z \}
=
\int
\mathbb{P} \left\{
\begin{gathered}
M_u < x, \ B_u + \xi < x, B_u + z + M_{T-v}^{**} < x, \\
B_u < \alpha, \ B_u + z < \beta
\end{gathered}
\right\}
\cdot \mathbb{P} \{
M_{v-u}^* \in d \xi, \ B_{v-u}^* \in d z
\}.
$$
and then in the zero-star vector $(B_u, M_u)$:
$$
\mathbb{P} \{ M_T < x, \ B_u < y, \ B_v < z \}
=
\int
\mathbb{1} \left\{
\begin{gathered}
\theta < x, \ \eta + \xi < x, \\
\eta < \alpha, \ \eta + z < \beta
\end{gathered}
\right\}
\cdot \mathbb{P} \{ M_{T-v}^{**} < x - z - \eta \}
\cdot \mathbb{P} \{
M_{v-u}^* \in d \xi, \ B_{v-u}^* \in d z
\} \cdot
\mathbb{P} \{
M_{u} \in d \theta, \ B_u \in d \eta
\}.
$$